# my code doesn't read Value from app.config

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, app-config

I am an absolute beginner to C-sharp.
my code doesn't read the value from `app.config.` I couldn't figure out what is missing.
The code opens Chrome but doesn't go to the Google website.
very much appreciated it if anyone can help with it.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("-no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), chromeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="URL" value="https://www.google.com/" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[image: main code]
[image: app.coonfig]

Comment: `The code opens the Chrome but doesn't go to Google` what code? Please update your post to include the code that's not working, not just images of code.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Mind your caps in the config file; it should be `<appSettings>` not `<AppSettings>`

Comment: Try renaming `AppSettings` xml node to `appSettings`

Answer (score 1):

Chrome opening says that driver initiated the correctly.

Appsettings spelling mistake.

```
   <appSettings>
      <add key="applicationurl"     value="www.google.com" />
 </appSettings>
```

else assign it to string/debug you can properly read the value from app.config rest of the code looks good.

Comment: It is not able Appsettings spelling. it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private object getASR(string key, Type type, object defaultValue)
{
 AppSettingsReader asr = new AppSettingsReader();
 try {
  return asr.GetValue(key, type);
  } catch (Exception) {
   return defaultValue;
  }
}

string urlValue = (string)getASR("URL", typeof(string), "defaultValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

`appSettings` is case sensitive, in your config file change `AppSettings` to `appSettings`

Comment: case sensitive doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the reason your code didn't navigate to google in the first place is that the url key was never set. Typically you need to read in any configuration you need for dotnet test projects along the lines that @james has suggested.

My suggestion would be to use configuration builder, which lets you pull in configuration from a json file, but also from environment variables if you so wish. You could set up a configuration helper like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


namespace TestProject1
{
    
    public class Config
    {
        public string? Url { get; set; }
        public string? Username  { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        // any other config you need

    }
    
    public static class ConfigProvider
    {
        
        public static Config Config;
        
        static ConfigProvider()
        {
            // Build config from various sources
            var configRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("testSettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
            
            // Bind config to new config object
            Config = new Config();
            
            // Bind params from testParams.json
            configRoot.Bind(Config);
        }

    }

    
}
```

Add a testSettings.json file to your test project root which looks something like:

```
{
    "Url": "www.google.co.uk",
    "Username": "myuser",
    "Password": "mypassword"
}
```

Update your csproj file to include the configuration builder dependencies, and also set it to copy your config file to the build folder:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup> 
   <!-- property group items -->
   </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <!-- other dependencies -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="testSettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Then you can then just reference any config you need in your tests like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  // driver setup here ...
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigProvider.Config.Url);
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#username")).SendKeys(ConfigProvider.Config.Username);
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#password")).SendKeys(ConfigProvider.Config.Password);
}
```

Hope this helps